# Mejor método para convertir a mayúscula

Tags: jquery

Tengo un formulario con varios campos y quiero que cuando se rellenen se transforme en mayúscula, tengo la siguiente función que funciona correctamente para casi todos los casos:

```
// CONVERT FORM TO UPPERCASE
jQuery(".form-control").focusout( function () {
    input=jQuery(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        input.val(input.val().toUpperCase());
    },50);
})
```

El "problema" viene cuando relleno algún campo con la opción autocompletar del navegador, que rellena varios campos a la vez, al no hacer focus en ningún momento en el input no aplica la función ¿alguna idea de como hacerlo mejor?

Comment: no hay un evento change?

Comment: @gbianchi no funciona cuando autocompleta el formulario

Answer (score 0):

Os comparto la forma para que funcione con autocompletar, como parámetro en el evento .on le podemos pasar diferentes estados, en este caso le paso el estado para cuando se auto completa un input y otro para cuando se cambia el foco:

```
jQuery("#step-2 .form-control").on("autocompletechange focusout", function () {
    input=jQuery(this);
    input.val(input.val().toUpperCase());
})
```

Comment: @padaleiana hecho!